# How to make 4 equal paddings (left, right, top, bottom) in a table cell?

Tags: tables, spacing

I want each cell in a tabular to have 4 equal paddings of exactly 15pt each.

How to make 4 equal paddings (left, right, top, bottom) in a table cell?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,longtable,ragged2e,pstricks}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\tabcolsep=1pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}

\def\pic{\begin{pspicture}(4,3)\psframe*(4,3)\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{A{0.5}|}}\hline
\pic&\pic\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Herbert's solution below apparently does not support displayed equations. Please compile with `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,longtable,ragged2e,pst-node,varwidth}
\psset{linecolor=blue}
\tabcolsep=1pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\newsavebox\TBox

\def\picB{\begin{pspicture}(4,3)\psframe*(4,3)\end{pspicture}}

\newenvironment{saveTBox}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\TBox}\varwidth{\linewidth}}
  {\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}%
   \fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=15pt\fbox{\usebox\TBox}}

\newcolumntype{B}{@{}>{\saveTBox}c<{\endsaveTBox}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|B|B|B|}\hline
    \[\rnode[r]{A}{y=f(x)}\] & \rnode[l]{B}{$\displaystyle y=f(x)$} & \picB 
    \ncline{A}{B}\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to let you know, I think this is a nicely formatted question; minimal example and helpful small screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same with allowing displayed eqiations ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,longtable,ragged2e,pstricks,varwidth}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\tabcolsep=1pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\newsavebox\TBox

\def\picB{\begin{pspicture}(4,3)\psframe*(4,3)\end{pspicture}}

\newenvironment{saveTBox}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\TBox}\varwidth{\linewidth}}
  {\endvarwidth\end{lrbox}%
   \fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=15pt\fbox{\usebox\TBox}}

\newcolumntype{B}{@{}>{\saveTBox}c<{\endsaveTBox}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|B|B|}\hline
\[ y=f(x) \] & \picB      
  \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. I will combine it with my real scenario "input-output table" using `listings.sty` and `fancyvrb.sty`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following to enclose horizontal material by a given padding on all sides, without changing its baseline.  Using that in a table should give you the desired result, except that you will have to make sure the tabular environment does not insert some additional padding.

```
\def\padded#1#2{%
   \setbox0\hbox{#2}%
   \dimen0=\dp0
   \setbox2\hbox{\hskip #1\vbox{\vskip #1\box0\vskip#1}\hskip#1}%
   \advance\dimen0 by #1%
   \leavevmode\lower\dimen0\box2}
```

You would use it as `\padded{10pt}{Blah pjqy}`.

Comment: Not that it makes any difference here, but the `%` after the `\dp0` causes TeX to expand the following token until it reaches something unexpandable (in this case, the `\setbox`) or until it finds a space token. One place it does matter is at the end of your macro. Try `\padded{10pt}{Blah pjqy}3`. The fix here is to just leave a space (a newline works) after the 2. Also, you should stick a `\leavevmode` before `\lower`, at least if you want to use this to start a paragraph ever.

Comment: True.  I actually had everything on one line, but when posting I split it and put the `%`'s there :)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,longtable,ragged2e,pstricks}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\tabcolsep=1pt
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\newsavebox\TBox

\def\pic{\begin{pspicture}(-5mm,-5mm)(4.5,3.5)\psframe*(4,3)\end{pspicture}}
\def\picB{\begin{pspicture}(4,3)\psframe*(4,3)\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| c | c|}\hline
\pic&\pic\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

 \fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=15pt
\begin{longtable}{| c | c|}\hline
\savebox\TBox{$\frac{x^2}{1+2x^2}$}\fbox{\usebox\TBox} & foo \tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}


\newenvironment{saveTBox}
  {\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=15pt%
   \begin{lrbox}{\TBox}}
  {\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox\TBox}}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\saveTBox}c<{\endsaveTBox}}

\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{longtable}{| B|B |}\hline
\picB & \picB\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert Although this solves the specific problem in the minimal example, it doesn't exactly answer the question: is there a way *within tabular* to add vertical and horizontal space around the contents of a cell.  Your solution just makes the pspicture have a border.  Is that the only reasonable solution? Is there a way to do this for arbitrary stuff in a table cell?  Using `array` and `\hspace` and `\rule`, within the column definition it's easy to do for text, but for the picture it didn't work.

Comment: @Alun: see edited example. In general it makes only sense for columns with a contents of the same width and height. Using `\fbox` with `\fboxrule=0pt` is an easy way to get it vertically centered.

Comment: @Herbert: Great.  Thanks.  The savebox idea is very useful. (BTW you have an extra `\newsavebox` command in the code, so it' won't compile as is.

Comment: @Alan: yes, I shouldn't insert only code snippets without testing it. I edited again the example and modified a bit the environemnt.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for answering. `\fbox` does not accept displayed equations. :-)

Comment: @xport: no, see another new answer

Answer (score 1):

One in Plain with XeTeX:

```
{
  \newskip\tableverticalpadding   \tableverticalpadding=1cm
  \newskip\tablehorizontalpadding \tablehorizontalpadding=1cm
  % Those are glues, by the way
  \everycr={\noalign{\vskip\tableverticalpadding}}
  \tabskip=\tablehorizontalpadding
  \vbox{% Just for the \hrule's
    \hrule height 1pt
    \halign{&\hfil$\vcenter{\hbox{#}}$\hfil\cr % horizontal/vertical centered
      Column with text&\XeTeXpicfile "i-stress-test.jpg" \cr
      \XeTeXpicfile "test-pattern.jpg" &\vbox{$$\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} math$$}\cr % added vbox around $$
    }
    \hrule height 1pt
  }
}
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: does it accept true displayed equations?

Comment: @xport: I updated my example for that, but if all you're doing is displayed maths, then it would make more sense to just redefine the preamble.