# How to make a table with centered images?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

On page 6 in [this](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~mab/education/astro500/reading/LS_2010.OE18_8430.pdf) PDF is there a table with centred pictures in the right column.

[image]

Does anyone know how to make such a table?

I am using pdflatex.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33257/how-to-vertically-and-horizontally-centre-text-and-images-in-different-table-c

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/how-to-make-4-equal-paddings-left-right-top-bottom-in-a-table-cell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the baseline of the images. Usually you center it to the height of the lower case characters (1ex).
This can be done using the `\raisebox` macro or using the `valign=m` key of the `adjustbox` package.

See also 
[How to align picture top left in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/how-to-align-picture-top-left-in-a-table) and 
[float left figure in titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33968/float-left-figure-in-titlepage/33970#33970) which are similar.

Here my code which also shows some of the other elements like bold math and stacking:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\providecommand{\textsubscript}[1]{%
    \mbox{$_\text{#1}$}%
}

\newcommand{\mystack}[1]{%
   \mbox{$
    \vcenter{%
        \hbox{\shortstack{#1}}%
    }%
    \mathsurround=0pt
   $}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \bfseries Scalar mode & 
    \bfseries Vector mode & 
    \bfseries Degeneracy & 
    $\mathbf{n_{\text{\bfseries eff}}}$ & 
    \bfseries Near field ($\mathbf{S_Z}$) \\
    \midrule
    LP\textsubscript{01} &
    HP\textsubscript{11} &
    2 & 1.44398 & \adjustimage{height=2cm,valign=m}{image1} \\
    LP\textsubscript{11} &
    \mystack{%
        HP\textsubscript{11} \\
        TE\textsubscript{01} \\
        TM\textsubscript{01}
    } &
    4 & 1.44381 & \adjustimage{height=2cm,valign=m}{image2} \\
    .. \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Originally cladding modes} \\
    \midrule
    .. \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{%
        *The LP\textsubscript{31} is four-fold ...
    }\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 14):

There are a range of approaches to vertically-centring material. The LaTeX3 ['coffin'](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins) concept makes this pretty easy to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\tablecoffin
\NewDocumentCommand\Vcentre{m}
  {%
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\tablecoffin{#1}%
    \TypesetCoffin\tablecoffin[l,vc]%
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 \Vcentre{A} & \Vcentre{B} & 
   \Vcentre{\includegraphics[width = 1 cm, height = 1 cm]{demo}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The idea here is that the 'coffin' is places such that it's vertical centre is in line with the current baseline, while it is horizontally placed at the current insertion point. (I have used the `demo` option for the `graphicx` package so that *something* appears: the black blob. For a real document, this is not needed.)

As Mark has already said, for the rules `booktabs` is the way to go.

Comment: [`xcoffins`](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental/xcoffins.pdf) has documentation now! Excellent. I've been waiting for this...

Comment: Wow, didn't know about xcoffins. This always bothered me a bit. Time to do some reading...

Comment: We're still not 100% sure on the best user interface, hence `xcoffins` being 'l3experimental'. Feedback most welcome :-)

Answer (score 8):

You'll get pretty close output for the table itself with the `booktabs` package. As for the images, a straightforward `\includegraphics` should do the trick.

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}m{1.5cm}m{1.5cm}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3\\
\midrule
One & Two & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{fig1}\\
Three & Four & \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{fig2}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: Just remember to fix the width or height of each image to make them look consistent.

Comment: Why is there just one **\** and no **\\**?